# Unable to build project in Xcode 12.5

Tags: xcode, nativescript

I am having problems after updating my macOS to sonoma 14.2.1.

## Current configuration: Xcode version: 12.5(12E262) MacOS version: 14.2.1 Nativescript version: 8.2.3 IOS platform version: 7.1.0

Below find error log:

```
IBPlatformTool: *** Failed to launch tool with description <IBCocoaTouchPlatformToolDescription: 0x6000037752c0> System content for IBCocoaTouchFramework-fourteenAndLater <IBScaleFactorDeviceTypeDescription: 0x600003775120> scaleFactor=2x, renderMode.identifier=(null): Failed to find or create execution context for description '<IBCocoaTouchPlatformToolDescription: 0x6000037752c0> System content for IBCocoaTouchFramework-fourteenAndLater <IBScaleFactorDeviceTypeDescription: 0x600003775120> scaleFactor=2x, renderMode.identifier=(null)'. Device type: IBSimDeviceTypeiPad2x (com.apple.dt.Xcode.IBSimDeviceType.iPad-2x) Sim runtime: (null)
** Please also include the output of `xcrun simctl list` and `xcode-select -p`.: Failed to find newest available Simulator runtime: No available runtime found from: [
    watchOS 7.4 (7.4 - 18T187) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.watchOS-7-4 (unavailable, The watchOS 7.4 simulator runtime is not supported on hosts after macOS
13.3.99.) ==> not available: Error Domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError Code=401 "The watchOS 7.4 simulator runtime is not available." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The watchOS 7.4 simulator runtime is not supported on hosts after macOS 13.3.99., NSLocalizedDescription=The watchOS 7.4 simulator runtime is not available., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=The watchOS 7.4 simulator runtime is not supported on macOS 14.2.1.},
    tvOS 14.5 (14.5 - 18L191) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.tvOS-14-5 (unavailable, The tvOS
14.5 simulator runtime is not supported on hosts after macOS 13.3.99.) ==> not available: Error Domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError Code=401 "The tvOS 14.5 simulator runtime is not available." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The tvOS 14.5 simulator runtime is not supported on hosts after macOS 13.3.99., NSLocalizedDescription=The tvOS 14.5 simulator runtime is not available., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=The tvOS 14.5 simulator runtime is not supported on macOS 14.2.1.},
    iOS 14.5 (14.5 - 18E182) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-14-5 (unavailable, The iOS 14.5 simulator runtime is not supported on hosts after macOS 13.3.99.) ==> not available: Error Domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError Code=401 "The iOS 14.5 simulator runtime is not available." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The iOS 14.5 simulator runtime is not supported on hosts after macOS 13.3.99., NSLocalizedDescription=The iOS 14.5 simulator runtime is not available., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=The iOS 14.5 simulator runtime is not supported on macOS 14.2.1.}, ] when matching for <IBCocoaTouchPlatformToolDescription: 0x6000037752c0> System content for IBCocoaTouchFramework-fourteenAndLater <IBScaleFactorDeviceTypeDescription: 0x600003775120> scaleFactor=2x, renderMode.identifier=(null), idiom=<IBIPhoneIdiom: 0x600000146da0> runtime=<IBCocoaTouchTargetRuntime: 0x60000055ca80> 2024-01-24 13:29:43.119 ibtoold[15689:204094] [MT] IBPlatformTool: *** Failed to launch tool with description <IBCocoaTouchPlatformToolDescription: 0x60000350fa60> System content for IBCocoaTouchFramework-TwelveThreeAndLater <IBScaleFactorDeviceTypeDescription: 0x60000350f340> scaleFactor=2x, renderMode.identifier=(null): Failed to find or create execution context for description '<IBCocoaTouchPlatformToolDescription: 0x60000350fa60> System content for IBCocoaTouchFramework-TwelveThreeAndLater <IBScaleFactorDeviceTypeDescription: 0x60000350f340> scaleFactor=2x, renderMode.identifier=(null)'. Device type: IBSimDeviceTypeiPad2x (com.apple.dt.Xcode.IBSimDeviceType.iPad-2x) Sim runtime: (null)

/Users/test/WorkSpace/projects/app1/platforms/ios/Pods/QBImagePickerController/QBImagePicker/QBImagePicker.storyboard: error: Compilation Failed.
    Underlying Errors:
        Description: Failed to find or create execution context for description '<IBCocoaTouchPlatformToolDescription: 0x60000350fa60> System content for IBCocoaTouchFramework-TwelveThreeAndLater <IBScaleFactorDeviceTypeDescription: 0x60000350f340> scaleFactor=2x, renderMode.identifier=(null)'. Device type: IBSimDeviceTypeiPad2x (com.apple.dt.Xcode.IBSimDeviceType.iPad-2x)

platforms/ios/app1.xcodeproj: warning: Building for iOS Simulator, but the linked and embedded framework 'TNSCore.framework' was built for iOS + iOS Simulator. (in target 'app1' from project 'app1') platforms/ios/app1.xcodeproj: warning: Building for iOS Simulator, but the linked and embedded framework 'TNSWidgets.framework' was built for iOS + iOS Simulator. (in target 'app1' from project 'app1') platforms/ios/app1.xcodeproj: warning: Building for iOS Simulator, but the linked and embedded framework 'TNSSideDrawer.framework' was built for iOS + iOS Simulator. (in target 'app1' from project 'app1')
** BUILD FAILED **
```

I tried updating my xcode to 15.2, but same issue

Comment: The errors are in the build log: "The iOS 14.5 simulator runtime is not available.", "The iOS 14.5 simulator runtime is not supported on hosts after macOS 13.3.99". Try choosing a simulator with more modern runtime, like iOS 17.